# How to make the variable dynamic in the given JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am using the given script for auto-complete multiple values in a project. Here the code is working with the static values as given in the following script, but I want to make these values dynamic. When I try to use dynamic values in the same script, it doesn't work.

Here I am providing you the working code with static values.

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",           // static values start
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"                  // static values end.
    ];
  });
  </script>
```

And here is the php code i tried to make dynamic the above script.

```
<?php 
    $recordd=mysql_query("select * from users ");
    while($row22=mysql_fetch_array($recordd)):
        $MessageObject[]='"' .$row22['fname']. '"';
    endwhile;
    $abc= implode(',<br>', $MessageObject);
?>
```

And now the script becomes as follow:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    <?php echo $abc; ?>     // here is the code i made dynamic. which doesn't work.
    ];

});
</script>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you share the Fiddle ?

Comment: Have you checked developers console? Are there any js errors? They should be as imploding with `<br />` will cause js-error.

Comment: no, there is no error, but it gives null result.

Comment: Get rid of the `<br>` in this `implode(',<br>', $MessageObject);` as this is adding html to a javascript array definition. Think about what you would actually hard code between a javascript `var availableTags = ['a','b','c'];` and generate that in the PHP variable you are echo'ing into the js code.

Comment: but i need to apply this, just in the same format as used in static case, that's i used this <br> above, as now i have shortened the code, plz go through it once again, may be you would provide me a solution, thanks...

Comment: Do you understand difference between html-markup and js-variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what data is in your tables `'fname'` column its a bit difficult to be definitive about an answer, but this would seem a simpler solution to your problem

```
<?php 
    $recordd=mysql_query("select * from users");
    $abc = '';
    while( $row22 = mysql_fetch_array($recordd) ):
        $abc .= '"' . $row22['fname'] . '",';
    endwhile;
    rtrim($abc, ',');
?>
```